# Upgrade from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

I got access to a computer using Ubuntu 16.04. Since it is out of support, I am in need to upgrade it to, say, 20.x.

To do this, I am prompted to execute `sudo apt-get update` before. But this gives the following error messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253
W: Failed to fetch https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial-cran35/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253
E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I assume that some have-a-look-see-URL became invalid. (especially probably `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/Packages)` What is / are the correct URL(s) and how to teach them to `apt-get`?

Until now, I have not saved important data / programs on the HDD, therefore backups are not relevant.

EDIT: Additionally, using an external medium is not allowed.

Comment: I would just do a new install using a usb.

Comment: Also be aware there is a https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thank you! I would be glad if it works without an external medium due to constraints. (no USB sticks allowed, no DVDs in the proximity, ... but root password existing).

Comment: I think its possible to install via network. then there would be an iso image, located somewhere else on the network and you could somehow refer to it like a usb. Havent't done that myself though.